# Strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup

Tags: profile

This seems to be a carry-over from:  http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,26411.0.html

I'm now receiving this error:

Strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::checkFieldsEmptyValues() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in CRM_Profile_Form->postProcess() (line 1315 of /home//public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form.php)

I just upgraded from 4.3

now using
- php 5.5
- drupal 7.38
- civiCRM 4.6.4 (a fresh install)

Has a fix been found?

---

### EDIT

...should have mentioned the php upgrade ;-)

I was able to control the warnings in the php.ini in php5.4 - with php5.5 they reappeared and nothing I've been able to do in the php.ini or .htaccess has been able to remove them. (Drupal platform and the errors are only in the log...I'm just trying to reduce the numbers of "errors" I see)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not really an error that would cause you any damage, so I would not classify it as an important bug. The name is 'strict warning', which means that it is a warning (not an error!) that the programmer has sinned against the PHP rules when a strict check has been done. So it should be fixed at some stage, but these type of warnings will never disappear entirely as they do not break anything.

I assume you are now seeing those warning because you are a site admin? In most live sites 'normal' users will not see these warnings, but that needs to be configured in your CMS (Drupal, Joomla or Wordpress).

Comment: any suggestions on where we should log these ?  Clutter Jira?  A list somewhere?  I find many php notices can be useful to capture but not necessarily important.

Answer (score 0):

A fix can be made in the Drupal settings.php file.

Add to the file:

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);